# pg-promise, using named parameters with nested objects

Tags: javascript, named-parameters, pg-promise

Is it possible to reference nested objects, when using named parameters with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), like the following example?

```
var obj = {
    name: 'John',
    address: {
        postcode: 'abc'
    }
};

db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE postcode=${address.postcode} AND name=${name}', obj);
```

At the moment the reference to the nested object is not resolved with the value, e.g. `${address.postcode}` is left as is and not replaced with `'abc'` in the query string.

Comment: The answer was updated. The library supports nested properties since [v6.10.0](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.6.10.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer is no longer valid since [v6.10.0](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.6.10.0) of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which started supporting [Nested Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#nested-named-parameters) natively.

And the code example provided in the question will just work as is.

---

**Only for [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) prior to [v6.10.0](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/releases/tag/v.6.10.0)**

The library only formats Named Parameters, it doesn't evaluate them, therefore no, you cannot do it, at least not directly like that.

But you can make sub-properties available to the query-formatting engine through functions:

```
var obj = {
    name: 'John',
    address: {
        postcode: 'abc'
    },
    addrCode: a => a.address.postcode // alias for accessing a sub-property
};
```

and then use `WHERE postcode = ${addrCode}`.

And the older / ES5 syntax, via `this` works also:

```
var obj = {
    name: 'John',
    address: {
        postcode: 'abc'
    },
    addrCode: function(/*a*/) {
        // a = this (can use both)
        return this.address.postcode;
    }
};
```

**UPDATE**

It is possible to make client-side evaluations work, but only with `$1, $2, ...` parameters:

```
db.query('... postcode = $1 AND name = $2', [obj.name, obj.address.postcode]);
```

NOTE: You cannot use evaluations like `${obj.address.postcode}` directly inside the query string, because the value won't be correctly escaped.

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t . Does the evaluation happen at the database level, then?

Comment: @arm5472 The library never does any evaluation, so I don't know what you mean. The library's query-formatting engine inserts all the values when you use the Named Parameters.

Comment: When I log the query, using [link](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query), the query property shows the `${name}` replaced by `'John'`, before it hits the database: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE postcode=${address.postcode} AND name='John'`

Comment: Evaluation happens on the server only in specific cases: a) For Prepared Statments; b) For Parameterized Queries. And in all those cases you only have access to the `$1, $2,...` variable syntax, but not to Named Parameters.